# PHP and MySql login error occuring

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the code no syntax or any error actually ocur but the problem is that the sql query don't seem to be reading the username and password:

here is what I get when I run the code and try to login:

```
That information is incorrect, try again Click Here
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);

include"db_connection.php"; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password'");



$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount ==1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id=$row["id"];
    }


    $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
    $_SESSION["manager"]=$manager;
    $_SESSION["password"]=$password;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
    }else{
        echo'That information is incorrect, try again<a href="index.php"> Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Admin Login Page</title>

<head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">

<div id="pageContent"><br/>
    <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
        <h2> Please log in To manage the store</h2>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin_login.php">
        User Name: <br/>
            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40"/>
            <br/></br>
            Password: <br/>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            <label>
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="LogIn">
            </label>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You check on `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`, but use `$_SESSION["manager"]` and `$_SESSION["password"]` in your query. Don't you need your $_POST values there?

In your code example, you never assign these post values to these session values.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that @jan but I am still getting same error

Comment: We're on our way :-) . What exactly is the error that you get?

Comment: :) ermm the error is when I try to log in it gives me `That information is incorrect, try again Click Here` when the username and password are correct @jan

Comment: Try `print "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password'"; die();` right after `$sql=...`. Copy the result and try to execute it directly in your database to see if you get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if username and password are in the POST request, but then you perform a preg_replace on the session request. I don't think that's right.

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["password"]);

..
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your mysql_query is not getting executed correctly. Can you print your $sql variable on screen and see if your $manager and $password variables are being output correctly? If so, can you copy that sql query and run in manually in phpmyadmin/ your database client to see if you get desired output?

Another possibility is that you can change the way you write your mysql_query

```
mysql_query('SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username="' .$manager. '" and password= "' .$password. '";') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: whats the print syntax and where do I place it. I tried the double quote but it still gives me same issue

Comment: just do echo $sql; die(); after your $sql statement and let us know what output you get.

Comment: I get `Resource id #4` printed out

Comment: You can try to get the values by fetching the array, 
$values = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
var_dump($values);